# What's the difference between os.system and subprocess.run?

Tags: python

I'm using `ffmpeg` to merge video and audio in linux/python. One way to do it is:

```
os.system(cmd)
```

But it will print a lot. So I used:

```
subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

instead.

Sometimes using `subprocess` causes the error: `[Errno 36] File name too long:`. But using `os.system` with the same `cmd` won't.

Why? How can I fix this error using `subprocess.run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `subprocess` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> If passing a single string, either `shell` must be `True` (see below) or
> else the string must simply name the program to be executed without
> specifying any arguments.

So you should set the `shell` argument to `True` so `cmd` can be properly parsed by the shell as a command with arguments:

```
subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, shell=True)
```